# This jar contains entries whose signer certificate will expire within six months

Tags: android

While generating key, I gave validity as 11,000 days which means more than 25 years. But when I verify the apk using jarsigner, it shows "This jar contains entries whose signer certificate will expire within six months". Why it shows validity for only 6 months even if I gave it for 11,000 days? Please help

Answer (score 1):

The default expire time is 180 days, just use the keytool to re-generate your signature. http://developer.android.com/guide/publishing/app-signing.html